# Не корректно определяется кодировки при использовании fseek более одного раза

Tags: php, кодировка

Приветствую!

У меня есть текстовый файл в кодировке `UTF-16LE` с `BOM`, который нужно распарсить.

Если открыть файл и первый раз прочитать данные(`fread`) в нужном смещение(`fseek`), то все ok(Кодировка определяется правильно). Но если после открытия файла, попытаться использовать `fseek` два и более раза, то `fread` возвращает какие-то китайские кракозябры.

Пример:

```
//Функция для открытия файла
function fileOpen($file) {
    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    //Потоковый фильтр для конвертации кодировки UTF-16 в UTF-8
    stream_filter_append($handle, 'convert.iconv.UTF-16LE/UTF-8');
    return $handle;
}

$handle = fileOpen('my_file.txt');
fseek($handle, 0x1f);
fread($handle, 27); //Все Ok

fseek($handle, 0x3a);
fread($handle, 30); //Строка в кривой кодировке

fseek($handle, 0x58);
fread($handle, 2); //Строка в кривой кодировке
```

Вы возможно подумаете, что указанно неправильное смещение или длина чтения, но это не так. Если в примере выше перед каждым fseek/fread, файл открыть заново, то все работает правильно:

```
$handle = fileOpen('my_file.txt');
fseek($handle, 0x1f);
fread($handle, 27); //Все Ok
fclose($handle);

$handle = fileOpen('my_file.txt');
fseek($handle, 0x3a);
fread($handle, 30); //Все ok
fclose($handle);

$handle = fileOpen('my_file.txt');
fseek($handle, 0x58);
fread($handle, 2); //Все ok
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Для начала посмотрите, что возвращает `fseek`

Comment: И после каждого `fseek` и `fread` посмотрите, что вернет `ftell`

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, fseek возвращает 0,  ftell возвращает last_fseek_pos + read_length

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, вообще причина оказывается в iconv - как-то не корректно конвертирует кодировки. Правда, все равно не понятно, почему все работает при первом чтении.

Comment: iconv может втыкаться на BOM. Значение, возвращаемое `ftell` после `fseek` совпадает с тем, куда позиционировались?